# Create order "queue" list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to Jquery and need a little direction to get started on setting up an order "queue" system. Short examples would help, but I'm looking more for a general outline and the know if what I'm wanting to do is even possible:

1) Have a "main" div where you select the item and enter the quantity for the item and select all the modifiers (I can do all this with text and checkboxes). Then click an "Add" button and it adds a summary of the order (maybe the quantity and item price total) to another div that "queues" up off to the side.

2) After hitting "add" the "main" div will clear all the boxes and allow me to add another item.

3) Have the ability to click the "summary" in the small div and re-display the order item.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a shopping cart script...... tons of them out there, just google it.

Comment: what I'm looking to do is no where as complicated as a shopping cart. It doesn't need to do payment or anything like that. I just want a simple way to create each order that is saved in our system.

Comment: If the information is visible off to the side why do you  need #3?

Comment: Because each item will include a quantity, price, discount, and a grid of about 30 check boxes for modifiers. So you have the ability to "edit" each item when clicking on item in the list off to the side. The list will just be a one line summary that says "1 x item name ($price)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of what you're asking for that should show you the basics of using jQuery to get values from the page:

HTML:

```
Select a Product: <select id="product">
    <option>Photoshop CS6</option>
    <option>Photoshop Elements</option>
    <option>iPhoto</option>
</select><br>
Digital Download <input id="digitalDownload" class="options" type="checkbox"><br>
Student Discount <input id="studentDiscount" class="options" type="checkbox"><br>
<br>
<button id="add">Add to Order</button><br>
<br>
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    // gather current order info
    var order = [];
    order.push($("#product").val());
    order.push("Digital Download: " + $("#digitalDownload").prop("checked"));
    order.push("Student Discount: " + $("#studentDiscount").prop("checked"));
    // put order info into summary
    $("#summary").append("<div>" + order.join(", ") + "</div>");
    // clear previous checked values
    $(".options").prop("checked", false);
});
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Rjmbx/

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This should really help me get started. I'll just have to figure out how to "recall" and order to be able to edit it after it ahs been added to the "summary" list.

Comment: I'm using PHP, so maybe I could accomplish this by setting the values in a $_SESSION array and then recall them from that?

Comment: Actually, ajax would be really cool. I'll see if I can figure this out.